# Scraping values from multiple table cells that contain a specific class within a specific tbody tag

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, domxpath

I would like to take data from the following tables, some I have already taken, others I just can't take them.

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="troop_details inAttack"
            >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="role">
                                                    <a href="/karte.php?d=91629">02]</a>
                                            </td>
                        <td colspan="11" class="troopHeadline">
                                                    <a class="markAttack" onclick="Travian.AttackSymbol.markAttackSymbol(29447487);return false;"><img id="markSymbol_29447487" class="markAttack markAttack0" src="/img/x.gif" title="mark attack" alt="mark attack" /></a>
                                                                        <a href="/karte.php?d=91628">Uanm attacks 01] #WorkInProgress</a>
                                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="units">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="coords">
                                                    &#x202d;<span class="coordinates coordinatesWrapper coordinatesAligned coordinatesltr"><span class="coordinateX">(&#x202d;0&#x202c;</span><span class="coordinatePipe">|</span><span class="coordinateY">&#x202d;&minus;&#x202d;28&#x202c;&#x202c;)</span></span>&#x202c;                                   </th>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u21" title="Phalanx: 0:04:17" alt="Phalanx" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u22" title="Swordsman: 0:05:00" alt="Swordsman" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u23" title="Pathfinder: 0:01:46" alt="Pathfinder" src="/img/x.gif" />                  </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u24" title="Theutates Thunder: 0:01:35" alt="Theutates Thunder" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u25" title="Druidrider: 0:01:53" alt="Druidrider" src="/img/x.gif" />                  </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u26" title="Haeduan: 0:02:18" alt="Haeduan" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u27" title="Ram: 0:07:30" alt="Ram" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u28" title="Trebuchet: 0:10:00" alt="Trebuchet" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u29" title="Chieftain: 0:06:00" alt="Chieftain" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                            <td class="uniticon">
                                <img class="unit u30" title="Settler: 0:06:00" alt="Settler" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                                            <td class="uniticon last">
                                <img class="unit uhero" title="Hero" alt="Hero" src="/img/x.gif" />                 </td>
                                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        
                <tbody class="units last">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Troops</th>
                                                            <td class="unit">
                                                            1                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                            <td class="unit none last">
                                                            0                                           </td>
                                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        
                
                <tbody class="infos">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Arrival</th>
                        <td colspan="11">
                            <div class="in">in&nbsp;<span  class="timer" counting="down" value="246">0:04:06</span>&nbsp;hrs.</div>
                            <div class="at"><span>at&nbsp;14:23:09</span><span> </span></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

In particular, I am interested in the coordinates and the units:

```
0
-28
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

To take the other parts of the html, I am using DOMXPath class, but in this case I cannot access that data.

EDIT: This is my code currently, I was able to get some of the data.

How can I remove the last character of the y coordinate? ie the parenthesis ")".

And how can I get the unit values? i.e. 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 etc.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($CasermaUtente);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$texts = [];
$count = 0;
foreach ($xpath->query("//table[contains(@class, 'troop_details') and contains(@class, 'inAttack')]") as $table) {
  $tablePath = $table->getNodePath();
   $texts[] = [
        $xpath->query($tablePath . "//td[@class='troopHeadline']//a[@href]/text()")[0]->nodeValue
  ];
  $orario[] = [
        substr($xpath->query($tablePath . "//div[@class='at']/span[starts-with(text(), 'at')]/text()")[0]->nodeValue, -8)
  ];
  $xcoord[] = [
        mb_substr($xpath->query($tablePath . "//span[@class='coordinateX']/text()")[0]->nodeValue,1)
  ];
  $ycoord[] = [
        $xpath->query($tablePath . "//span[@class='coordinateY']/text()")[0]->nodeValue
  ];
$count = $count + 1;
}

?>

<table width="350px" border="1">
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<$count ; $i++) { ?>
<tr><td align="center"> <?php $stampa_xcoord = implode($xcoord[$i]);
echo $stampa_xcoord; ?>
</td>
<td align="center"> <?php $stampa_ycoord = implode($ycoord[$i]);
echo $stampa_ycoord; ?>
<td align="center"><?php $stampa_stringa = implode($texts[$i]);
echo $stampa_stringa; ?>
</td>
<td align="center"> <?php $stampa_orario = implode($orario[$i]);
echo $stampa_orario; }?>
</table>
```

My output is something like that:

[image]

Comment: @mickmackusa had entered the code but it did not make me post the question because the error said "too much code". However I changed the question and entered the code. When I ask a question it is because I have already researched the answer without any results, it is a new field for me so many times seeing the result already leads me to understand faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an inner loop to pick up all of the `unit` values.

`strstr()` with a 3rd parameter of `true` is a good technique to use when you want to isolate the substring before the first occurence of another substring.  This is reliable if `]` is guaranteed to exist in the `text` strings.  If that symbol is not guaranteed to exist, then `explode()` may be more oppropriate (in which chase you unconditionally access the first element of the array that explode creates).

Rather than echoing a lot of html markup with php variables, I like how clean the `printf()` syntax is.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/H0PZP))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($CasermaUtente);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$texts = [];
$orario = [];
$xcoord = [];
$ycoord = [];
$unita = [];
foreach ($xpath->query("//table[contains(@class, 'troop_details') and contains(@class, 'inAttack')]") as $i => $table) {
    $tablePath = $table->getNodePath();
    $texts[] = strstr($xpath->query("$tablePath//td[@class='troopHeadline']//a[@href]/text()")[0]->nodeValue, ']', true);
    $orario[] = substr($xpath->query("$tablePath//div[@class='at']/span[starts-with(text(), 'at')]/text()")[0]->nodeValue, -8);
    $xcoord[] = ltrim($xpath->query("$tablePath//span[@class='coordinateX']")[0]->nodeValue, '(');
    $ycoord[] = rtrim($xpath->query("$tablePath//span[@class='coordinateY']")[0]->nodeValue, ')');
    foreach ($xpath->query("$tablePath//tbody[contains(@class, 'units') and contains(@class, 'last')]//td[contains(@class, 'unit')]/text()") as $unit) {
        $unita[] = trim($unit->nodeValue);
    }
}

echo '<table width="350px" border="1">';
foreach ($texts as $i => $text) {
    printf('
        <tr>
            <td align="center">%s</td>
            <td align="center">%s</td>
            <td align="center">%s</td>
            <td align="center">%s</td>
            <td align="center">%s</td>
        </tr>',
        $xcoord[$i],
        $ycoord[$i],
        $text,
        $orario[$i],
        implode(' ', $unita)
    );
    echo "\n"; // for readability in online demo
}
echo '</table>';
```

Output:

```
<table width="350px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">‭0‬</td>
            <td align="center">‭−‭28‬‬</td>
            <td align="center">Uanm attacks 01</td>
            <td align="center">14:23:09</td>
            <td align="center">1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and for everything.